# preg_match same last 3 digit of a string

Tags: php, preg-match

Guys I'm kinda dumb in making formula so please can you help me out?

I got this strings

```
string 'tfa_517' (length=7)
string 'tfa_528' (length=7)
string 'tfa_528' (length=7)
string 'tfa_529' (length=7)
string 'tfa_529' (length=7)
```

Can you help me combine the two 'tfa_528' and the tfa_529 and leave the one with no pair alone? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean `combine` ? string concatenation?

Comment: yes. But not like 'tfa_528'. 'tfa_528'; more of imploding them on an array

Comment: So you only want one listing for each?

Comment: Any questions, issues?

Comment: thanks Chris, but It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How does it not work? Is the output in the answer an incorrect interpretation? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I've fixed it, I used !array_key_exist hehehe thanks for the references

Comment: Sounds like you were trying to do something different than `So you only want one listing for each?`... You might as well post your answer and update the question to what your answer is answering. This way future visitors might find this useful.

Comment: exactly, but thanks for the info though

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this.

1. `Explode` it on new lines so that each line is a separate value in an array.

   Use `array_unique` to remove all duplicates.

   `Implode` it back with the "glue" used in the `explode` to have it back as a string.

```
<?php
$string = "string 'tfa_517' (length=7)
string 'tfa_528' (length=7)
string 'tfa_528' (length=7)
string 'tfa_529' (length=7)
string 'tfa_529' (length=7)";
$newstring = implode("\n", array_unique(explode("\n", $string)));
echo $newstring;
```

Output:

```
string 'tfa_517' (length=7)
string 'tfa_528' (length=7)
string 'tfa_529' (length=7)
```

Function docs:

1. http://php.net/explode
2. http://php.net/array_unique
3. http://php.net/implode